# Method RegisterAsBrowser of object IWebBrowser2 failed

Tags: excel, vba

While running Macros, i am encountering this error - 'Method RegisterAsBrowser of object IWebBrowser2 failed'. Initially for past few months, Macros was working fine but yesterday I got a new laptop, and I was trying to run Macros. But it is displaying this error. When the macros executes successfully, it redirects to the first page of our organization's tool in Internet Explorer browser.

Please help me in fixing this issue. Since I am not technically sound, I have no idea what this error is about. My work is stuck due to the same.

Comment: Have you updated all the drivers including the most recent version of internet explorer? What about security? do you have any new security programs installed that your old computer doesnt?

Comment: You claim your macro stopped working, but it still works on your old computer. The problem is therefore not in the macro.   On new Windows 10 computers [Internet Explorer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41628)  is not installed by default, is it installed on your (new) computer?